# Problem linking with Boost.Filesystem

Tags: gcc, linker-errors, boost-filesystem

I am trying to use the functions from boost::filesystem to change my current working directory (and create it if necessary).  I am getting linking errors:

```
SBDir.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
SBDir.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
SBDir.cpp:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
```

But I **am** linking against the boost libraries??!?  I use the following:

```
-lboost_system -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem -lboost_filesystem-mt
```

And I know it can find them because with `-Wl, -t` I get:

```
-lboost_system (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/libboost_system.so)
-lboost_system-mt (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/libboost_system-mt.so)
-lboost_filesystem (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/libboost_filesystem.so)
-lboost_filesystem-mt (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.so)
```

FWIW: I'm using gcc `Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu54.4.3`.

Comment: provide the compilation and linking commands

Comment: I'd be happy to, but as they're part of a long Makefile I'm hesitant to spam the question with unnecessary information.  Is there something specific I could add?  (e.g are you looking specifically for the linker flags I'm using?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I couldn't figure out what went wrong -- so I tried un-installing the Ubuntu boost package and building it from scratch.  I upgraded to 1.45.0 & now everything links.  Not sure whether this was a version specific problem or not, but if I learn more later I'll come back and update.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error message with boost 1.46 (standard with Ubuntu 11.10) and I had to add -lboost_system which I didn't need in 11.04 and boost 1.42.  It doesn't answer your question but possibly of interest to others brought here by googling the error message.